# Linux - check IPC stats

Tags: linux, ipc

What is the best way of checking current status of different types of IPC in Linux (including uids) ?

I want to inspect named pipes, half duplex pipes, unix domain sockets, signals.

I know for sys V we have ipcs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lsof(8)` is probably your best option.  Lesser options include `ipcs(1)`, `fuser(1)`, `netstat(8)`, `ps(1)`, and rummaging through `/proc`.

Comment: which one is for half duplex pipes ?

Comment: @Jake There is no such thing as a "full duplex pipe".  There are only pipes, named pipes (a.k.a. FIFOs), and sockets.

Comment: Oh so I meant pipes

Comment: I was using  lsof | grep pipe ... will that give me pipe or FIFO ?

Comment: Also I used ps s -A to count signals .. please tell if that's correct .. thanks !

Comment: `lsof(8)` will show both pipes and FIFOs.  Please consider reading the manual rather than asking me to summarise it for you.  As for `ps s -A`, could be, I don't have access to a Linux machine right now.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. I'll check the manual.