# Linux - check processes using IPC channels

Tags: ipc

This is related to my previous [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212679/63934).

Given that I can find the statistics of IPC channels in my Linux system (e.g. sys V IPC), how can I find which processes are using certain IPC channel (sending via channel; receivers are usually mentioned in command outputs).

For example, `ipcs` gives me a list of shared mem id's on the machine. How can I find which processes are using that shared memory ?

The other IPC's I am interested in (these are the commands I used to find the statistics):

- Pipes: `lsof | grep pipe`
- UNIX Domain sockets: `netstat -n`

Answer (score 4):

You also use `ipcs`, but add extra options:

```
wouter@gangtai:~$ ipcs

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages    

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      
0x0052e2c1 32768      postgres   600        56         20                      
0x00000000 17924097   wouter     600        33554432   2          dest         
0x00000000 49446914   wouter     600        524288     2          dest         
[...]
wouter@gangtai:~$ ipcs -i 17924097 -m -p

Shared memory Segment shmid=17924097
uid=1000    gid=1000    cuid=1000   cgid=1000
mode=01600  access_perms=0600
bytes=33554432  lpid=3808   cpid=1457   nattch=2
att_time=Fri Jul  3 10:43:28 2015  
det_time=Fri Jul  3 10:43:28 2015  
change_time=Fri Jul  3 10:03:00 2015
```

`lpid` is the "last accessor" PID; `cpid` is the "creator" PID.

The `-i` parameter needs the id of the IPC object (shared memory segment, message queue, or semaphore) that you want to inspect. The `-m` flag is because we're inspecting a memory segment, and the `-p` says we want to see process IDs.

See `man ipcs` for the full story.